Does disabling GC make CGO callbacks safe?
I'm integrating a c library into my go program, and one of the functions I have to use have a callback interface. As is common with these, the function in question also takes a pointer, that it will pass you as a parameter when it calls the callback.
The code looks a little something like this. The wrapping has to do with the fact that this was the only way for it to accept the types, as directly passing the go callback to the c function complained that the callback didn't match type *[0]byte.
/*
extern bool goCallback(void*);

static bool callback(void* data)
{
    return goCallback(data);
}

static WrapCall(void* data)
{
    return callRelevantCFunction(callback, data);
}
*/
import "C"

func goCallback(p unsafe.Pointer) {
    data := (*MyObjectType)(p)
    //do things
}

func main() {
    obj := &MyObjectType{}
    C.WrapCall(unsafe.Pointer(obj))
}

My understanding is that under normal circumstances if obj contains other go pointers, it would be unsafe to deference those pointers. They might invalidated if the GC decides to move these the objects pointed at, or if a reference is dropped clean them up.
Unfortunately, the data needed by the callback fairly large with many nested go objects.
In order to avoid a large amount of work refactoring this object so the data lives in C memory, would it suffice to disable the GC for the duration of the C function call that may invoke the callback?

How do you intend to temporarily disable the GC? It might be safe with no GC, and you will probably have to also specify cgocheck=0, but none of that is specified anywhere.

I was planning on doing is temporarily, but it shouldn't be a problem to disable for the duration of the program if that would be safer.

I ask because there is no defined way to temporarily disable GC. Again, it might work, but this is not specified so you get to keep all the pieces when it breaks. Note there may also be differences in padding and alignment that could cause problems when trying to use Go types in C.

C does not use the go type at all, it passes it through to a callback that's written in go. Can the GC see pointers in a golang function that has been invoked as a callback by the main C function, or do we stay in the C stack?

Oh yeah, I forgot that this was just being passed back to a Go callback. The GC can see any pointer that was allocated by Go. The call does end up back on the Go stack because the Go function has a different calling convention (which is why you need the C wrapper)

Ok got it, so my mental model was a little off. If I'm understanding correctly:

If the C code itself assesses go memory through a pointer passed to it, this is unsafe unless that memory is pinned.
If the C code invoke the go callback, and the go callback assesses go memory, then this is safe.

I previously though that assessing go pointers if we entered C land at any point in the logical stack, then it was unsafe.

The “unsafe” part here is that while the C function is holding the pointers before the callback, it might be possible that they are unreachable from Go and get GC’ed
